# When is the subobject classifier of a functor category a cogenerator?

Tags: ct.category-theory

The passage from any small category **C** to its set-valued functor categoy
$\hat{\mathbf C}:=\mathrm{Fun}(C^{\ast},\mathrm{\bf  Set})$  i.e.
the full Yoneda-embedding $Y\colon \mathrm{\bf C} \to \hat{\mathrm{\bf C}}$ into 
the presheaf category can be considered as an universal completion-process.

A functor category such as
$\mathrm{Fun}(\mathrm{\bf C}^{\ast},\mathrm{\bf Set})$ is a category
which is ``almost as good as the target category $\mathrm{\bf Set}$''.
In particular such a functor category is a topos and
has an injective subobject classifier $\Omega$.

In the simplest case of $\mathrm{\bf Set}$, which can be considered as 
the special case $\mathrm{\bf C}=\mathrm{\bf 1}$,  the subobject classifier
is a two-element set $\{0,1\}$ and has the property, that it is a
cogenerator. (An object $C$ of a category is called *cogenerator*, if
for any two  distinct morphism  $f,g\colon X\to Y$  there is a morphism
$s\colon Y\to C$ such that $s\circ f\neq s\circ g$). A cogenerator $C$ allows
to separate the morphisms in the category and so to ``resolve''
the category, if $C$ happens to be an injective object.

It seem to be natural to ask whether the subobject classifier of any 
set-valued functor category is a cogenerator. This can not be
 the case, since in the special case $\mathrm{\bf C}={\mathbb Z}_2$ (category with one object
generated by an non-trivial involution)
which leads to the functor category  $\hat{\mathbb Z}_2=\mbox{Fun}({\mathbb Z}_2^{\ast},\mathrm{\bf Set})$ of sets with a
${\mathbb Z}_2$-action, the subobject classifier $\Omega$ is a two-element
set $\{0,1\}$ with the trivial  ${\mathbb Z}_2$-action. This object $\Omega$
is not a cogenerator of $\hat{\mathbb Z}_2$ since the the two-element set
with the nontrivial ${\mathbb Z}_2$-action gives an object $X$ of
$\hat{\mathbb Z}_2$, whose nontrivial automorphism cannot be separated 
from the identity by any morphism from $X$ to $\Omega$. Hence there are
conditions needed before the subobject classifier of a set-valued functor 
category can be a cogenerator.

Under which precise conditions for the category $\mathrm{\bf C}$
is the subobject classifier $\Omega$ of its free-cocompletion
$\hat{\mathrm{\bf C}}$ a cogenerator?

Comment: You may want to look at Borceux's paper *"When is $\Omega$ a cogenerator in a topos?"*, available here: http://www.numdam.org/item?id=CTGDC_1975__16_1_3_0

Comment: @Theo: Why don't you post this as an answer? I mean this is exactly what was asked here.

Comment: @Theo: Thank you for your link. Unfortunately Borceux's paper does not answer the question.

Comment: @Martin: Borceux studies in his paper indeed the corresponding question in an arbitrary topos and proves the following result:

Theorem: Let $E$ be a topos. If the subobjects of 1 form a set of generators, the $\Omega$ is a cogenerator.

As Borceux also remarks, this fact is true for a much wider class of topoi such as the category of graphs. I would like to know for which set-valued functor categories it is true.

Comment: Another paper that might be of interest is Generating families in a topos by Kenney: http://ftp.gwdg.de/pub/misc/EMIS/journals/TAC/volumes/16/31/16-31abs.html (I'm not claiming this answers the question, but maybe it provides some insights).

Comment: As Kenney mentions in his paper, the subobject classifier is a cogenerator in the category of simplicial sets.

Comment: I think you need Peter Johnstone's [hyperconnected-localic](http://www.numdam.org/item/CTGDC_1981__22_1_3_0.pdf) factorisation of geometric morphisms. (If that's not enough, add a more familiar epi-mono factorisation.)